# Alert Data in JQuery which is in PHP for loop.

Tags: php, jquery

I have a code which is in PHP Loop.

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i++; $i < 10) { ?>
<div class="test">
<textarea name="test-textarea" for="<?php echo $i ?>"></textarea>
<button value="<?php echo $i ?>">Save</button>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Now I want to alert data in JQuery. When I click button which value is 7 then it will alert data of textarea which is for value is 7.

Any Help will be Appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the value of the button in an attribute selector, to find the linked textarea.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    alert( $('textarea[for="' + $(this).attr('value') + '"]').val() );
});
```

It would be better to use `data-*` attributes for your custom data.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test button").click(function(){
        alert($(this).parent().find('textarea').val());
    });
});
```

See [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/psKk3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) { ?>
<div class="test">
<textarea id="<?php echo $i ?>" name="test-textarea" for="<?php echo $i ?>"></textarea>
<button onclick="javacript:alertvalue(<?php echo $i; ?>);" value="<?php echo $i ?>">Save</button>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function alertvalue(var tid){
var txt=document.getElementById(tid).value();
alert(txt);
}
</script>
```